# How use `createBrowserRouter` deployng all into IPFS network?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web3js, ipfs

I write a simple app in react and in this app i use the `createBrowserRouter` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { ThirdwebProvider } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
import { Sepolia } from "@thirdweb-dev/chains";
import "./styles/globals.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";
import xxx from "./routers/xxx";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <App />, errorElement: <ErrorPage /> },
  { path: "xxx", element: <xxx /> },
  { path: "xxx/:xxx", element: <xxx /> },
  { path: "xxx/:xxx/:xxx/", element: <xxx /> },
  { path: "xxx/:xxx/:xxx/:xxx", element: <xxx /> },
  { path: "xxx/:xxx", element: <xxx /> },
]);

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container!);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThirdwebProvider
      activeChain={Sepolia}
      autoConnect={true}
    >
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ThirdwebProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals(console.log);
```

When I deploy to the IPFS network they get me a link with a path like: `"https://ipfs.thirdwebcdn.com/ipfs/hashOfBuildFolder"`

According to the doc they say to do in this way

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <App />, errorElement: <ErrorPage /> },
  { path: "xxx", element: <xxx /> },
  { path: "xxx/:xxx", element: <xxx /> },
  { path: "xxx/:xxx/:xxx/", element: <xxx /> },
  { path: "xxx/:xxx/:xxx/:xxx", element: <xxx /> },
  { path: "xxx/:xxx", element: <xxx /> },
], {
 basename:"/relative/path/"
});
```

but in this case is the hash of the build folder and every time I change the value of `basename` the hash change so the link change.

Answer (score 0):

`basename:"/relative/path/"` I think there should not be a trailing slash and you should add a slash in each route. 
**For example:** 
`basename` should be: `basename:"/relative/path"`
and in the rest of the object's path should be: `{ path: "/xxx", ... }`

Comment: But usign the IPFS network i dot know before the deploy the resl relative path, is this my problem

Answer (score 0):

I switch to [createHashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-hash-router) so now i have no more the issue.
This is just a way to not have the problem not the solution.